# Sharepoint Site not getting created

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to create Sharepoint Site based on SalesLeadPipeline template but its is giving the following error

Feature '75a0fea7-9507-49c7-a473-0ce55c18ef89' is not installed in this farm, and can not be added to this scope.

Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.

I also installed the Expense Reimbursement & Approval template apart from SalesLeadPipeline template using the stsadm tool.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't install the "Expense Reimbursement" template correctly (that matches feature ID 75a0fea78...

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/dd328fce-6d16-434f-b4bf-a53deac8eaad

```
stsadm.exe -o retractsolution -name ExpenseReimbursementApproval.wsp -immediate 
stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs
stsadm.exe –o addsolution –filename ExpenseReimbursementApproval.wsp
stsadm.exe –o deploysolution –name ExpenseReimbursementApproval.wsp -allowgacdeployment -immediate
stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs
```

Answer (score 0):

In Central Admin, have a look in Operations - Solution Management to see if the solution has not deployed successfully. It might give you some hints.

Secondly, is the GUID reported in you post the GUID for either of these features? You should be able to find the FeatureID in the feature.xml file. It may be easiest to unpack the WSP files and check inside each feature.xml file.